# Django: failed to overwrite handler404

Tags: python, django

Part urls.py (for testing):

```
old_handler404 = handler404
def custom_page_not_found(request, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
    if request.path.startswith('/myapp/api'):
        try:
            return HttpResponseNotFound( json.dumps( {'info': 'page not found'} ),
                    content_type='application/json')
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Exception:', e

    #return HttpResponseNotFound('Page Not found', content_type='text/html; charset=utf-8')
    try:
        res = old_handler404( request, *args, **kwargs )
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Exception:', e
    return res


handler404 = custom_page_not_found
```

Trying to overwrite existing 404handler, for rest apis (urls starting with `/myapp/api`), return 404 and error messages in JSON if urls not matched, for the remainings, return 404 and existing `not found` pages if url not matched.

For `/myapp/api`, it works fine. but for the remainings, it returned `500` instead of expected `404`. No exception information shown.

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Exception: 'str' object is not callable

**UPDATE**

how about the following codes? any side-effects?
In fact, in my django app `myapp`, there are several sub-apps. Some sub-apps are finished by others, and the `api` sub-app finished by me. I just would not like to change/touch others' logic and codes. How about the following codes? Any welcomes welcomed. Thanks.

```
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found as old_page_not_found

#old_handler404 = django.views.defaults.page_not_found
def custom_page_not_found(request, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
    if request.path.startswith('/myapp/api'):
        try:
            return HttpResponseNotFound( json.dumps( {'info': 'page not found'} ),
                    content_type='application/json')
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Exception:', e

    #return HttpResponseNotFound('Page Not found', content_type='text/html; charset=utf-8')
    try:
        res = old_page_not_found( request, *args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Exception:', e
    return res
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @marcusshep post updated.

Comment: Which Django version are you on?

Comment: @knbk django version is 1.7

Comment: `except Exceptino as e:` _Exceptino_

Comment: handler404 is not what you think it is